# sed replace string between commas, with input from other file, on matched fields

Tags: sed

Say I have `credentials` file, with the following:

```
db: my_db
user: my_username
dbprefix: db_prefix
```

And `config.php` file like this:

```
---

public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'user';
public $password = 'pass';
public $db = 'some_db';
public $dbprefix = 'uk4o9_';

---
```

I would like to read line by line from `credentials` and substitute
appropriate values in `config.php` file, matching fields on the left from
`credentials` with variables in `config.php` file

```
`db` from `credentials` would substitute `$db` value in `configuration.php`
`user` from `credentials` would substitute `$user` value in `configuration.php`
etc..
```

So at the end I have something like this:

```
---

public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'my_username';
public $password = 'pass';
public $db = 'my_db';
public $dbprefix = 'db_prefix';

---
```

I would like to do it with `sed` and not too much of a shell script, if it is
possible.

I began with something like this, just to test it out, if I can replace value in
between commas with line from `credentials` but I failed, obviously cannot
access backreference like this:

```
read line < credentials; sed -n -e "/\$db\s=\s\'(.*)\'/ {
    s/\1/$line/
    p
}" configuration.php
```

However still have no idea how would I compare values on the left of `:`, for
appropriate lines in `configuration.php` to be acted upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` to generate a sed script from the credentials, then pipe it to another sed to process the config:

```
sed "s%\(.*\): \(.*\)%s/public $\1 = '.*'/public $\1 = '\2'/%" credentials \
| sed -f- config.php
```

Comment: What does `%` stand for? `sed -f-` reads script from stdin? I can see the pattern of `credentials` file, in `\(.*\): \(.*\)` and all parts, but can't get the big picture..

Comment: @branquito: Yes, `-f-` reads the script from `-` which is stdin. I use `%` instead of `/` in the first sed expression to avoid excessive backslashing (because I use `/` in the inner expression). Try just running the first pipeline part to see the script.

Comment: So in `s/A/B/` B part, you can have entire new sub-sed `s/../../` ?

Comment: I got it, in replace-with part you put entire literal sed expression to be used later, right? I was confused because I thought it's gonna be evaluated. And it's not because `/` is now ordinary character.

Comment: After running first part, I see this..  `s/public $\(db\) = '.*'/public $db = 'db_name'/`. Why are `(` escaped?

Comment: @branquito: these are capturing parentheses which must be backslashed in sed.

Comment: I understand that, I am not asking for parenthesis in your command, but in generated first part, before sending to second sed command.. You are not backreferencing anything from that part on..

Comment: @branquito: True. They were needed in the first solution I tried before I fully understood the specification. Fixed.

Comment: I was just about to post that `\$\1` version ;)